# Send data amongst three activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have 3 activities, that connect like this:
A -> B -> C.

On A you input a text that will be used in C, then B opens and you input another text to be used in C. But when C  opens, produces null errors.

I came up with a solution, to start A then go directly to C and onCreate of C, start B as if it was going from A to B.

Is there a better solution? Is my solution decent or will it cause more problems than it fixes? Thanks for any help.

Comment: My solution would be to save data in SharedPreference / SQLite, instead of passing via Bundle and keeping track on each activity's onResume() / onCreate(). If data is sensitive, store as encrypted data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options - `Intent` extras, `SharedPreferences`, `SQLite` database, internal/external storage, `Application` class, static data classes etc.

For situation you've explained, I recommend using `SharedPreferences` to store data, it's relatively easy approach and you can access stored data at any time from any `Activity` or class, here is a simple usage guide:

**Input data into SharedPreferences:**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("YourPrefsFile", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "Elena");
 editor.putInt("idName", 12);
 editor.apply();
```

**Get data from SharedPreferences:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("YourPrefsFile", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
  String name = prefs.getString("name", "");
  int idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 0);
}
```

Comment: I thought that shared preferences is  substitute to savedInstance state and  saves data only to be used by one activity. Could you make a simple example with shared preferences

Comment: @ManosRasidakis - I've updated my answer with a simple example

Comment: What is Mode_Private ?

Comment: @ManosRasidakis it's a constant, which makes the data private - available only to your app. You can set it public via MODE_WORLD_READABLE,MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE - making your data available by other apps

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 solutions in this case the

1. first one is which you mentioned
2. the second one is using an intent with put extra in every activity that you will go from
3. the third solution is using a static variables so that the variables will not be affected if activity reopened (not recommended)
4. the fourth one you can use shared preference to save the data (which will be the best solution in my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very good idea as their may be delays in starting the activity as you would be doing some other operations as well in the onCreate method of activity B and C. Will cause performance issues in future due to delay in showing the activity.

Things you can do...

- If the data is very small lets say a key value pair then why not use shared preferences.
- Or use a database to store the data as and when it gets created, after which when the activity is created query it and show it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, You can **pass the input to next activity through intent**.

Since it is a text input,

```
intent.putExtra("A_Activity_Input","YourinputString"); //in activity A
```

Then Activity B starts, Get the string using

```
String Input_A_Activity=getIntent().getStringExtra("A_Activity_Input");
```

After When you are starting C activity from B, send both data using intent

```
intent.putExtra("A_Activity_Input",Input_A_Activity);
intent.putExtra("B_Activity_Input","YourinputString");
```

In Activity C, Get the string from the intent.

Since you just need a data to process, **Storing it in SQL or SharedPref or something else wastes memory**